# Black Planes in Blender

Tags: opengl, blender

Blender noob trying to render an object but certain parts of it keep coming out black. I'm not sure why. My image is here which might help:

[image: some faces come out black]

A few extra details:

- The shelves I've been trying to render are just a collection of planes which I've  aligned to form shelves
- All of them have no material or texture on them
- Despite this, the very furthest plane (back of the shelves) and the front one which says laundry render properly in white, but the others render in black
- I've tried adding material/texture to all of them, but they still come out black
- My light source is set to "Sun" and sits a little bit behind the camera and shines directly onto the shelves

Is this a lighting issue?? If so any suggestions for how to fix?

Comment: Are these planes right on top of each other? You should put a little distance between them if they are.

Answer (score 0):

Your "normals" are flipped. In other words, each surface has a "front" and "back" side. The backs of yours are facing in (which makes sense, when you consider the method you created the volume...you're looking at the inside surfaces).

To fix your issue, select the dark faces and do `Mesh->Normals->Flip`

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to solve it. I tried that - clicked on a mesh, went to edit mode, selected it then hit CTRL+F and then Flip normals. But still comes out black. I checked and all of them are "double sided" as well. Tried turning that on and off and it doesnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are not getting any light on their faces because of the angle compared to the light source.  Try adding a point light source to your scene just in front of your shelf objects to see if that changes the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Flipping the 'normals' worked for me, only after switching to render cycles from blender render. Hope that helps someone else.